# In Export to excel not getting no. in proper format in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to export Grid View in excel and I get formatting issue like number is not getting proper(e.g -1.523E+11)
also 0 is missing, where value is leading with 0.

```
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                DataTable dtGetReportBank = new DataTable();
                dtGetReportBank = objPO.GetReportBank(id);
                gridData.DataSource = dtGetReportBank;
                gridData.DataBind();

                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "BankCMS" + ".xls"));
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                StringWriter sw1 = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htw1 = new HtmlTextWriter(sw1);
                gridData.AllowPaging = false;
                dvContent.RenderControl(htw1);
                Response.Write(sw1.ToString());
                Response.End();
                Btn.Visible = false;
```

Comment: An important factor to consider is how Excel stores its values. Numbers are stored internally as numbers and therefore won't show leading zeros unless the cell formatting is set that way. A quick way around this is to save values as text by prepending a ' in front. Eg '0123 will display in Excel as 0123. Otherwise you can store as a number and tell excel to format in the format "0000" which will force four digits. Though no idea how you'd do that through asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Amol,

The best to way to handle this is using OpenXML.

Create a SpreadsheetDocument -> WorkbookPart -> WorksheetPart -> Cell

While creating a Cell, specify the Cell.DataType and you will get whatever you expect.

Once the Document is filled, use SpreadsheetDocument.Save() method to save the same

Hope this helps!

Comment: The method you have written has very less control over specifying the data type of Cell, which in my view is causing issue.